# Returning wrong values of true/false in list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, set, tuples

**QUESTION**

WRITE A code to check if a list of 'N' English words can be written using only one row of the keyboard. If that's the case, make a list containing 'True' or 'False' options.

Input :

First line must read the value of 'N'. 
Second line onwards read 'N' Words

Example : if the value of N = 3 then the list of English words are [POTTER, EQUITY, LIRIL] then the output is  [True, True, False]

**MY CODE**

```
N=int(input("enter number of elements: "))
words=input("enter the words separated by a space: ")
wl=words.split()
print("list of words is" , wl)
l2=[]
final=[]
a=['q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p']
if N<0:
    print("Invalid Input")
else:
    for i in range(0,N):
        ele=wl[i]
        l2.append(ele)
        new=ele.split()
        if new <=a:
            re1='True'
            final.append(re1)
        else:
            re2='False'
            final.append(re2)
    print(final)
```

final list shows true even letters from other rows of the keyboard are used. can anyone point out where my mistake is and help me out in fixing this code?

Comment: `new <= a` is a strange comparison. Think about it. But a question: your keyboard has more than one row, right? This code just looks at one... Also think about how upper and lower case letters compare...

Comment: There is multiple issues in there, it's hard to tell what you thought things would do, that's why it's hard to tell how you made mistakes. For example, add `print(new)` right after defining `new`. Does `split` do what you think it does? Another one, as already pointed out by trincot: What do you think `new <= a` compares and how? What are `new` and `a` at this point?

Comment: You prob. can make the `rule` clearly in the Problem statement.  Even we can look at our keyboard and figure this out!  ;-)

Comment: Also please note that `'True'` and `'False'` are not the same as `True` and `False`.  Ironically, `'False'` is a string that always evaluates to `True`.

Comment: @trincot got it! i somehow read the question as "list of 'N' English words can be written using only *top* row of the keyboard " and didnt even realise while typing out this question here lmao. for upper/lower case i added .upper() with the input part

Comment: @TimRoberts ohh that is right

Comment: @DanielHao i completely misread the question as "list of 'N' English words can be written using only top row of the keyboard " and only realised later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 rows of letters on your keyboard

```
row1="QWERTYUIOP"
row2="ASDFGHJKL"
row3="ZXCVBNM"
```

Granted that the 3rd row won't produce any words because it hase no vowels but you would still need to check the second row for words such as GLAD, FLAG, HALL, etc.

For each individual word, it will be possible to write it on one row, if all its letters are on the same row:

```
if all(letter in row1 for letter in word) \
or all(letter in row1 for letter in word):
```

With this you should be able to populate your final result by looping over the word list (no need to bother with indexes).

```
for word in wl:
    if all(letter in row1 for letter in word.upper()) \
    or all(letter in row2 for letter in word.upper()):
       final.append(True)
    else:
       final.append(False)
```

Comment: `N=int(input("enter number of elements: "))`
`l1=[]`
`final=[]`
`for i in range(N):`
    `words=input("").upper()`
    `l1.append(words)`    
`row1="QWERTYUIOP"`
`row2="ASDFGHJKL"`
`row3="ZXCVBNM"`
`if N<0:`
    `print("Invalid input")`
`else:`
   ` for i in range(len(l1)):`
        `ele=str(l1[i])`
        `if all(letter in row1 for letter in ele) or all(letter in row2 for letter in ele) or all(letter in row3 for letter in ele):`
            `final.append(True)`
        `else:`
            `final.append(False)`
    `print(final)`

Comment: this is what i ended up with. it works but i still havent understood how to do it without indexes?

Comment: You originally used `words.split()` to get the word list (`wl`) which was right so I didn't repeat it in my post.  This readily creates a list that you can iterate through using a for-loop.  Since split() will separate the words, you don't need to ask the user for a number of words (which might be inconsistent).

Comment: To avoid using indexes, you simply need to let the for-loop go through the items in the list of words (`for word in wl:`)  instead of going through a range of indexes that you then have to apply on the list (`for i in range(len(wl)): word=wl[i] ...`)

Comment: If you are required to first ask for a number of words, you should input words one by one in a loop and process each word as you go to feed your final list: `for _ in range(NumberOfWords):` `word = input("enter a single word:") ...` *The `_` in the for-loop is used to ignore the iteration number because you are only interested in repeating your process (not the index value).*

Comment: Nice use of `all`.

Comment: @AlainT. okay, understood now. thank you :D